# overGrive crashes on Ubuntu 18.04 even with oauth2client installed

Tags: 18.04

overGrive crashes on Ubuntu 18.04, maybe because that it is an en_IL version. 
This is the trace back:

```
[INFO] Linux-4.15.0-32-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-18.04-bionic
[INFO] Desktop : ubuntu
[CONFIG] Loading User Settings GUI mode
[CONFIG] Auto Sync : True
[CONFIG] Convert Google Docs : False
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "overgrive.py", line 5591, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 545, in getdefaultlocale
    return _parse_localename(localename)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py", line 477, in _parse_localename
    raise ValueError, 'unknown locale: %s' % localename
ValueError: unknown locale: en_IL
```

Any idea how to handle this will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

In the past, a workaround regarding similar errors was to add

```
unset LC_CTYPE
```

At the bottom of `.profile`, then `source .profile` to apply the changes.
Give that a try.